# How Do I Increment and Display Variable Counter Using Meteor Template Helper?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars, meteor-helper

I got a `itemInCollection = new Meteor.Collection('stuff')` collection and I use `itemInCollection.find()` to get all the items in it. Now I iterate over the resulting cursor to show the `name` attribute in the template.

```
<head>
  <title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  {{#each item}}
     {{counter}} : {{name}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Now I just want to represent a number in front of the name, like e.g.

```
 1. John
 2. Doe
 3. Darling
```

How can the **counter** be realized in the helper function? I tried the following:

```
Template.hello.helpers({
  'item': function() {
    return itemInCollection.find();
  },
 'counter': function() {
   var counter = PrimerList.find().count(),
      arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
      arr.push( i + 1 );
    }
    return arr;
  }
});
```

and in the template i wrote this:

```
  {{#each item}}
      {{#each counter}} {{this}} {{/each}} : {{name}}
  {{/each}}
```

but that gave me like:

```
1 2 3 John
1 2 3 Doe
1 2 3 Darling
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do that:

```
Template.hello.helpers({
    'item': function() {
        return itemInCollection.find().map(function(document, index) {
            document.index = index + 1;
            return document;
        });
    }
});
```

---

```
<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  {{#each item}}
     {{index}} : {{name}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extend your items in helper, like

```
items: function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return itemInCollection.find().map(function ( item ) { 
        return {
            name: item.name,
            counter: counter++
        };
    });
}
```